# Desugared form of "let in"

Tags: f#, functional-programming

What do the `let (x = 0) in x * x` translate to? A function `(fun x -> x * x) 0)` ? - This would make sense, as `let` bindings are expressions - and expressions must return values (just like functions).

Example:

```
let result1 = 
    (fun n1 -> (fun n2 -> 
    (fun n3 -> n1 + n2 + n3 ) 3) 2) 1

let result2 = 
    let n1 = 1 in
    let n2 = 2 in
    let n3 = 3 in
    n1 + n2 + n3

let result3 = 
    let n1 = 1
    let n2 = 2
    let n3 = 3
    n1 + n2 + n3
```

Am I right to assume that `result3` is a sugared form of `result2`, and `result2` a sugared form of `result1`?

Short: Do `let in` bindings translate to functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can almost see `let x = e1 in e2` as a syntactic sugar for `(fun x -> e2) e1`.

At the basic level, the two expressions mean the same thing - the compiler will probably compile them differently (depending on optimization levels and how it inlines things), but you could often use the second notation instead of the first one.

The one case where they differ is that ML-languages (including F#) only *generalize* function types written explicitly using the `let` keyword. This means that if you use `fun`, the language won't treat it as a generic function. If you want a generic function, you have to use `let` (and this is not just a compiler artifact, this is actually part of the language).

For example, the following uses `let` and it works:

```
let id = (fun x -> x) in ignore(id 1); ignore(id "A")
```

But the following does not work, because `id` is not a generic function:

```
(fun id -> ignore(id 1); ignore(id "A")) (fun x -> x)
```

Answer (score 4):

The plain old `let` is just the lightweight syntax form of the verbose `let … in`.

From [MSDN: Verbose Syntax (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx):

> nested `let` bindings:
>
> **Lightweight syntax:**
>
> ```
> let f x =
>     let a = 1
>     let b = 2
>     x + a + b
> ```
>
> **Verbose syntax:**
>
> ```
> let f x =
>     let a = 1 in
>     let b = 2 in
>     x + a + b
> ```

The `let` bindings within these function don't translate to functions themselves, however. Both of these translate to identical CIL code:

```
f:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0003:  add         
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.2    
IL_0005:  add         
IL_0006:  ret
```

Note that the only function here is the outer function `f`. The variables `a` and `b` are evaluated as constants within the scope of `f`.

Comment: Do `let (a = 2) in 2 * 2` translate to `(fun a -> a * a) 2` or is there some difference?

Comment: Thanks! - I can't help wondering, what if ex. the variable `a` isn't a constant? But a call to a function: `let a = getNumberFromFile() in ...` - Would it then be translated (or equivalent) to: `let f x = (fun a -> x + 2) (getNumberFromFile())` ? (`b` is still a constant).

Comment: Yeah, it would compile to the same CIL code, but it would not create a new function at the CIL level for `a`.

Comment: Got it. So `result1`, `result2` and `result3` in my question would compile to the same code, but wont create a new function per nested let binding - instead the expression of each let binding is either constant (and their value therefore resolved at compile time), or a function in the sense that it calls a function (`call`, `callvirt`) and assigns the value to the let binding - of course this is only at CIL level.

Comment: @ebb Pretty much. A `let` binding without a parameter (`let a = …`) compiles to a constant or a local variable taking the value of an expression (e.g. return value of a function). A `let` binding with a parameter (`let f x = …`) may compile to a function if the compiler cannot inline it more (note that in all the above examples `f 5` compiles to a constant `8`).

Comment: @ebb Also note, a `let` binding could have an lambda expression on the right of the `=`, e.g. `let a = fun x -> …`, in this case, the result is the same as `let a x = …` so it may result in a function at the CIL level.

Answer (score 1):

`let x = <val> in <expr>` is functionally equivalent to `(fun x -> <expr>) <val>`.

- `<expr>` is an expression
- `<val>` is a value

The `in` keyword is optional.

Comment: By functionally equivalent you mean that they do the same, but not necessarily compiles to the same code (like @p.s.w.g mentions in his answer?)

Comment: @ebb I believe in the case of the `let` the `(fun x -> <expr>)` is conceptually there, but is inlined. If you explicitly use the `(fun x -> <expr>) <val>` version, you are explicitly creating a function. So the compiler is certainly not *required* to inline it. So while they are functionally equivalent, the `let` version seems like it should be at least as efficient as the `fun` version. I don't have access to the compiled code view right now to verify.

Comment: @ebb Whether you include the `in` keyword or not is not going to change the compiled code. That's just a choice for how you want your source code to look.